# Parsing JSON gives few separate elements put toghether as one

Tags: php, json, decode

I get following JSON (which I have validated [here](http://json.parser.online.fr)):

```
{
    "name": "Brian",
    "agentid": "12345",
    "username": "bob",
    "passcode": "bob01",
    "call": {
        "aa": "11",
        "bb": "22",
        "cc": "33",
        "dd": "44"
    },
    "call": {
        "aa": "111",
        "bb": "222",
        "cc": "333",
        "dd": "444"
    },
    "call": {
        "aa": "1111",
        "bb": "2222",
        "cc": "3333",
        "dd": "4444"
    },
    "call": {
        "aa": "11111",
        "bb": "22222",
        "cc": "33333",
        "dd": "44444"
    }
}
```

When I put this through `var_dump(json_decode($json, true));`, it gives me:

```
array(5) { 
    ["name"]=> string(5) "Brian" 
    ["agentid"]=> string(5) "12345" 
    ["username"]=> string(3) "bob" 
    ["passcode"]=> string(5) "bob01" 
    ["call"]=> array(4) {
        ["aa"]=> string(5) "11111" 
        ["bb"]=> string(5) "22222" 
        ["cc"]=> string(5) "33333" 
        ["dd"]=> string(5) "44444" 
    }
}
```

It looks like the first three `call` elements are overwritten.

How to parse this JSON and retain *all* `call` elements?

Comment: that's not json, or, at least, doesn't make sense. create a list of `call`s.

Comment: It's your logic that's false. You shouln't use twice the same key in on dictionary. Use an array of entries like @KarolyHorvath suggested.

Comment: The `call` should be an array `[]` of objects `{}`.

Comment: Yes because an array can only contain 1 key for `call`.

Comment: JSON arrays have no keys

Comment: array has. and in an array, can not be 2 elements with the same key.

Comment: It may be valid JSON syntax, but it's not something that could have been BUILT via a json_encoder. You cannot have multiple different items sharing the SAME key in an object/array. There's no way this could've come from a native data structure, and was probably built in smaller pieces.

Comment: @lolka_bolka JSON array elements has **no** keys (there're only indices), so there's no way for `2 elements with the same key` because here is no key for content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is valid JSON syntax, but content makes no sense. Having more the one key of the same name is wrong. You should make single `call` and turn it into JSON **array** where you would store all objects:

```
{  
   "name":"Brian",
   "agentid":"12345",
   "username":"bob",
   "passcode":"bob01",
   "call":[  
      {  
         "aa":"11",
         "bb":"22",
         "cc":"33",
         "dd":"44"
      },
      {  
         "aa":"111",
         "bb":"222",
         "cc":"333",
         "dd":"444"
      },
      {  
         "aa":"1111",
         "bb":"2222",
         "cc":"3333",
         "dd":"4444"
      },
      {  
         "aa":"11111",
         "bb":"22222",
         "cc":"33333",
         "dd":"44444"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks and I will reappraise my idea of "valid" in light of the comments above :)